# Did I need server for "android-rcs-ims-stack"?

Tags: android, stack, rcs

I want to use "android-rcs-ims-stack" on two devices with android OS. I want to transfer files between them. Did I need dedicated server and what software should be installed on it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a server for this as operators have already setup servers for this. What you need is mobile numbers which are RCS capable so that they can authenticate and connect to the servers.